# Code works in everything except for Wapka. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I spent about three hours on coding a div generator last night, and I have tested it. It works. The problem is this:
I use [Wapka.mobi](http://wapka.mobi/) to create websites for free (since I am too young to have an official programming career), and I run [this website](http://m-thatplace.wapka.mobi). On the site, I have a programming hub with useful tools for newer programmers ( a hexadecimal and rgba calculator at the moment), and I'd like to add the generator to it. Sadly, this code doesn't work in Wapka. The strange part is that it works everywhere else. Notepadd++ runs it fine, and so does just about every html editor I know. Here's the code.

```
<script language="javascript">

function genDiv(){

var brdr = document.getElementById('udBorder').value;
var brdrw = document.getElementById('udBorderWidth').value;
var brdrr = document.getElementById('udBorderRadius').value;
var pad = document.getElementById('udPadding').value;
var padl = document.getElementById('udPaddingL').value;
var padr = document.getElementById('udPaddingR').value;
var padt = document.getElementById('udPaddingT').value;
var padb = document.getElementById('udPaddingB').value;
var back = document.getElementById('udBackground').value;
var bc1 = document.getElementById('udFirstC').value;
var bc2 = document.getElementById('udSecondC').value;
var c = document.getElementById('udColor').value;

var brdrch = document.getElementById('borderAlt');
var padch = document.getElementById('paddingAlt');
var backch = document.getElementById('backAlt');

var result = document.getElementById('divRes');

if((brdrch.checked == true) && (padch.checked == true) && (backch.checked == true)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else if((brdrch.checked == true) && (padch.checked == true) && (backch.checked == false)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else if((brdrch.checked == true) && (padch.checked == false) && (backch.checked == false)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding:" + pad + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else if((brdrch.checked == true) && (padch.checked == false) && (backch.checked == true)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding:" + pad + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else if((brdrch.checked == false) && (padch.checked == true) && (backch.checked == true)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else if((brdrch.checked == false) && (padch.checked == true) && (backch.checked == false)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else if((brdrch.checked == false) && (padch.checked == false) && (backch.checked == true)){
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding:" + pad + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
}else{
result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding:" + pad + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\"> </div>";
}
}

</script>
<div style="border:solid 1px #000;padding:5px;text-align:center;background:#FFF;color:#000;">

<h1>&lt;div&gt; Generator</h1>
<hr/>

<div id="border">
<b>Border:</b> <input type="text" id="udBorder" value="solid" placeholder="Enter Border Type"/>
<br/>
Width: <input type="text" id="udBorderWidth"  value="1" placeholder="Enter Border Width"/>
<br/>
Radius: <input type="text" id="udBorderRadius" value="5" placeholder="Enter Border Radius"/><br/>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="borderAlt" onclick="borderAdj();"/> No border

<script language="javascript">

function borderAdj(){
var ch = document.getElementById('borderAlt');
var b = document.getElementById('border');

if(ch.checked == true){
b.style.opacity = '.5';
}else{
b.style.opacity = '1';
}
}

</script>

<hr/>

<div id="padding">
<span id="padding1">
<b>Padding:</b> <input type="text" id="udPadding" value="2" placeholder="Enter Padding Amount"/>
</span>
<span style="display:none;" id="padding4">

Padding-left: <input type="text" id="udPaddingL" value="2" placeholder="Enter Padding Amount"/><br/>
Padding-right: <input type="text" id="udPaddingR" value="2" placeholder="Enter Padding Amount"/><br/>
Padding-top: <input type="text" id="udPaddingT" value="2" placeholder="Enter Padding Amount"/><br/>
Padding-bottom: <input type="text" id="udPaddingB" value="2" placeholder="Enter Padding Amount"/><br/>

</span>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="paddingAlt" onclick="padAdj();"/> Padding by side
</div>
<script language="javascript">

function padAdj(){
var ch = document.getElementById('paddingAlt');
var oneP = document.getElementById('padding1');
var fourP = document.getElementById('padding4');

if(ch.checked == true){
oneP.style.display='none';
fourP.style.display='';
}else{
oneP.style.display='';
fourP.style.display='none';
}
}

</script>

<hr/>

<div id="background">

<span id="normBack">
<b>Background:</b> <input type="text" id="udBackground" value="#FFFFFF" placeholder="Enter Background"/>
</span>

<span id="linBack" style="display:none;">

First Color: <input type="text" id="udFirstC" value="#FFFFFF" placeholder="First Color"/><br/>
Second color: <input type="text" id="udSecondC" value="#000000" placeholder="Second Color"/>

</span>

<br/>

<input type="checkbox" id="backAlt" onclick="backAdj();"/> Linear background

</div>
<script language="javascript">

function backAdj(){
var ch = document.getElementById('backAlt');
var n = document.getElementById('normBack');
var l = document.getElementById('linBack');

if(ch.checked == true){
n.style.display='none';
l.style.display='';
}else{
n.style.display='';
l.style.display='none';
}
}

</script>

<hr/>

<div id="color">

<b>Color:</b> <input type="text" id="udColor" value="#000000" placeholder="Enter Color"/>

</div>

<hr/>

<input type="button" onclick="genDiv();" value="Generate!"/>

</div>

<br/><br/>

Result Code:<br/>

<textarea id="divRes" cols="20" rows="5" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
```

I apologize for the code being so long, I just can't find anything wrong with it. At this point, I blame Wapka. Thanks in advance.

Here's a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4nkmxep9/

Comment: Hello.  I've added a jsfiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/4nkmxep9/  Is there a link on Wapka that is currently hosting this functionality?  This will help me to understand the issue

Comment: http://m-thatplace.wapka.mobi/site_4.xhtml Here it is, I haven't put it on the main site due to it's lack of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that somewhere along the line, Wapka has `escaped` characters within your javascript text, which explains why it is not working.

For example, your line:

```
if((brdrch.checked == true) && (padch.checked == true) && (backch.checked == true)){
```

Has been translated to:

```
if((brdrch.checked == true) &amp;&amp; (padch.checked == true) &amp;&amp; (backch.checked == true)){
```

So the line is being terminated at the first `;` , resulting in invalid javascript.

I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with Wapka, but maybe there is  another mechanism you can use to import javascript which doesnt escape the characters as if they were all html markup.

Have you tried specifying `<script type="text/javascript">` in your script tags? (Not sure if that will help?)

---

### Update

Alternatively, as a bit of a hack, you could nest your logical AND statements instead, e.g.

```
if(brdrch.checked) {
    if(padch.checked) {
        if(backch.checked) {

            //do your thang
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Update #2

Logical re-factoring

```
if(brdrch.checked) {
    if(padch.checked) {
        if (backch.checked) {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        } else {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        }
    } else {
        if (backch.checked) {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding:" + pad + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        } else {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"padding:" + pad + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        }
    }
} else {
    if(padch.checked) {
        if (backch.checked) {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        } else {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding-left:" + padl + "px" + ";padding-right:" + padr + "px" + ";padding-top:" + padt + "px" + ";padding-bottom:" + padb + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        }
    } else {
        if (backch.checked) {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding:" + pad + "px" + ";-webkit-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-moz-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-o-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");-ms-background:linear-gradient(" + bc1 + "," + bc2 + ");color:" + c + ";" + "\">   </div>";
        } else {
            result.innerHTML = "<div style=\"border:" + brdr + " " + brdrw+"px" + ";border-radius:" + brdrr + "px" + ";padding:" + pad + "px" + ";background:" + back + ";color:" + c + ";" + "\"> </div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Look Mom - no 'ands

Comment: Well, either I had a syntax error, or it didn't work. It rendered the code useless in Notepad++, I still have the original in my site though.

Comment: Hello. I've re-factored the logic to omit all & symbols.  (See Update #2)  Here is a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4nkmxep9/2/.  Hope it works :D

Comment: Thanks a ton, this fix was successful! It works fine (I forgot to add a general background specification in the css, but I can fix that), and I hope they fix that sometime.